# Bootstrap grid not displaying properly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

OK So Im FINALIZING a clients website and Im using bootstrap 3 I have created this code for the website. It displays everything in the the first div and the second (middle) Div correctly but It doesnt display anything after that. I put it in a fluid container and It still doesnt display the last div nor any of the code that I have after this. I am using Notepad++ to edit and check my errors live and I dont see any error here? what could be the problem with this.

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: rgba (0,0,0,0.8)">
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
            <img src="../images/BluelinesandBigFaces.jpg" class="img-responsive"><br><button class="btn-warning" onmousedown="player1.loadPlaylist(0)">PLAY</button>
            <img src="../images/pantiesdrop.jpg" class="img-responsive"><br><button class="btn-warning" onmousedown="player1.loadPlaylist(2)">PLAY</button>
            <img src="../images/sidechick.jpg" class="img-responsive"><br><button class="btn-warning" onmousedown="player1.loadPlaylist(3)">PLAY</button>

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dWU4e6kFaaw"</iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
            <img src="../images/BluelinesandBigFaces.jpg" class="img-responsive"><br>
            <img src="../images/BluelinesandBigFaces.jpg" class="img-responsive"><br>
            <img src="../images/BluelinesandBigFaces.jpg" class="img-responsive">

            </div>
    </div>
<br>
    <div class="row" style="background-color: rgba (0,0,0,0.8)">
        <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- MusicPageAd -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-7512006871298343"
     data-ad-slot="6094032318"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="container-fluid" >
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10" style="background-color: rgba (0,0,0,0.8)">
                <!--iFrameToVerticalPostPage-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2" style="background-color: rgba (0,0,0,0.8)">
                Welcome Msg<br>
                Twitter Feed<br>
                Cost 2 Coast Side Ad
                Facebook Feed<br>
                ReAdvertisement<br>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tag closing issue:

```
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dWU4e6kFaaw"> // <-- close this
</iframe>
```

Always try to look at start and end tags - in any editor and even on code snippet above, if they're not the same color - there's something wrong!